# docker: OCI runtime create failed: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []string: unknown

Tags: docker, debian-based

I've got this error after update my docker on Linux Astra (Debian based OS). It happened when I was trying to run `sudo docker run hello-world`

Full text of the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []string: unknown.
```

`sudo docker -v` returns `Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d`

Comment: possibly relevant: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Алексей Козлов from ru.stackoverflow.com. The problem can be solved with following:

1. Remove the broken version of Docker

```
dpkg -l | grep -i docker

sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce  
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
```

2. Install docker-ce

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   jessie \
   stable"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install docker-ce

sudo apt-get install docker-ce-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall brocken version.
   See answer @volkoshkursk
2. Add "frozen" repo

```
    echo "deb https://download.astralinux.ru/astra/frozen/orel-2.12/2.12.13/repository orel contrib main non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
    apt update
```

3. Look all available package versions.

```
    apt-cache madison docker.io
```

4. Install oldest.

```
    apt install -y docker.io=17.12.1-0ubuntu1
```